# Fetch Data from BLE Device every 15 min using core bluetooth in iOS

Tags: swift, xcode, bluetooth, ios11

I have specific requirement where i want to fetch data from the connected Ble Device every 15 mins for a period of time like form 10:00 PM to 10:00 AM. Can it be done when my app is in background and device is locked. Obviously, user won't keep the app in foreground for so long. Any suggestions on how to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

In background mode(app was killed) iOS device cant communicate with BLE.
Only scan BLE device which have service uuid.

Only background scanning is possible in iOS.

So u can get notification while peripheral was found in Background mode.

Answer (score 0):

It may be achieved but unfortunately you need to solve this from device perspective.

Your device will need to wake up and initiate connection with your phone whenever you need to sync data. It will wake up your application and even launch it if it was terminated. You can then initiate a standard background process for which you have limited time to do whatever needs to be done. When complete you should disconnect from your device and wait for the process to be repeated.

There might be some hacks like using silent push notifications to wake up your app and try to connect but Apple will most likely not allow this plus there is a great chance your BT will simply not work in that state. Still it is something to try if you really need it.

Answer (score 0):

You have the problem that you can't have a timer in an iOS app. Therefore you have some options that require specific behaviour of the peripheral.

One option is to let the app first connect, and always upon disconnect, it tries to reconnect. Then simply make the peripheral don't advertise for 15 minutes. As soon as it advertises again your app will be woken up because it connected. You can then fetch your data.

Another option is to be constantly connected and have a timer in the peripheral that notifies data every 15 minutes.

Both options requires you to have background capabilities enabled in your app and State Preservation and Restoration.